# Why does it only print one character (Python)

Tags: python, string, random

Why does it only print one character?

```
import random
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890?!*-_.,'
b = ''
for i in range(10):
  a = (random.choice(letters))
  b = "".join(a)
print(b)
```

This is an example of what i get:

```
R
```

Im not trying to make a very good and safe password gen for commercial use, it's more about the concept and the learning.

Comment: `a = random.choice(letters); b = b+a`

Answer (score 1):

you replace one letter in your loop , if you want to add + :

```
import random
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890?!*-_.,'
b = ''
for i in range(10):
  a = (random.choice(letters))
  b += a # here 
print(b)
```

output:

```
Gg_LZ!?y-a
```

but also you can simplify abit :

```
import random
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890?!*-_.,'
a = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(10))
print(a)
```

also you might wanna use `string` module :

```
import random
import string

a = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation) for i in range(10))
print(a)
```

or you can use `random.sample`:

```
import random
import string
b = "".join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation,10))
print(b)
```

Comment: Knew it would be something simple like that. Thanks alot!

Comment: @sindre you are welcome , also see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

'''

```
import random
   letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890?!*-_.,'
   b = []
   for i in range(10):
     a = (random.choice(letters))
     b.append(a)
   print(b)

['b', '5', 'K', 'J', '*', 'c', 'T', 'j', 'v', '5']

pw = ' '.join(b)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that will help you with learning, using list comprehension:

```
import random
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890?!*-_.,'
b="".join([random.choice(letters) for i in range(10)])
```

**Or using string and numpy**

```
import numpy as np
import string
letters=string.digits+string.ascii_letters+'?!*-_.,'
b="".join(np.random.choice(list(letters),size=10,replace=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the join and not the +, you have to tell join it must join a and b:

```
import random
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890?!*-_.,'
b = ''
for i in range(10):
  a = (random.choice(letters))
  b = "".join([b,a])
print(b)
```

Sample outout:

```
p5qvFvairr
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already gotten once solution. Here are to other changes to consider.

Option 1:

```
import random
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890?!*-_.,'
a = ''
for i in range(10):
    a +=random.choice(letters)
print(a)
```

Option 2: Use `sample` instead of repeatedly using `choice`.

```
import random
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890?!*-_.,'
b = "".join(random.sample(letters,10))
print(b)
```